# Chain tasks without passing the previous results in Python Celery

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I want to create a chain of async event to be executed one after the other but I am not interested in passing the result of the previous one to the next one, just execute them in a chain. I am have something like this:

```
tasks = []
for document_id in document_ids:
    tasks.append(
        utils.task(
            'tasks.update_document',
            document_id=document_id,
        ),
    )

result = chain(*tasks).apply_async(ignore_result=True)
```

My task receiving this is something like :

```
@app.task
def update_document(document_id, *args,**kwargs):
    if not isinstance(my_variable, int):
        raise TypeError
    return f'Done: {document_id}'
```

BUT it seems that the `ignore_result=True` doesnt do anything and instead I get the result of the previous task to the next one and it make the second task fail. Anyways to just make the tasks chained but not add any other argument to the following tasks?

Comment: Someone answered that to me a while ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django post\_save signal, executing chained tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76646396/django-post-save-signal-executing-chained-tasks)

Comment: It might not be the same problem but the answer answers your question.

Comment: I am not sure what the suggestion is to pass immutable=True to the cahin method? If it is the immutability, not sure what other side effects that will have i dont care if it is mutable or not I just dont want it to add the previous result, this seems like a nuclear solution to a mosquito problem kind of thing :-)

Comment: Sorry, actually you might want to use [groups](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#groups) instead of chains *If you call the group, the tasks will be applied one after another in the current process, and a GroupResult instance is returned that can be used to keep track of the results, or tell how many tasks are ready*

Comment: @Daviid groups are executed in parallel i want them to be in series

Comment: Are you sure? *the tasks will be applied one after another in the current process* make me think they're executed in series not parallel.

Comment: @Daviid but at the very top it starts with `A group can be used to execute several tasks in parallel.` which makes sense otherwise how could you send tasks in parallel right?

Answer (score 0):

I think the deleted answer and the comment under the question actually provide correct direction for the solution. I think the OP is misunderstanding what is an immutable signature is. [From docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#signatures)

> A signature() wraps the arguments, keyword arguments, and execution options of a single task invocation in a way such that it can be passed to functions or even serialized and sent across the wire.

And

> Partials are meant to be used with callbacks, any tasks linked, or chord callbacks will be applied with the result of the parent task. Sometimes you want to specify a callback that doesn’t take additional arguments, and in that case you can set the signature to be immutable

What the documentation is actually saying that signature of the task is meant to be used as "input" for the task, in case of `chain` and other workflows, the "input" may be extended with a result from the previous call. Meaning, the "immutability" of the signature applies only for the task call itself, so that the workflows would not affect it. You can extend the arguments in the call signature in the future if you want.

This notion is confirmed with this quote from the same doc

> Note the use of .si above; this creates an immutable signature, meaning any new arguments passed (including to return value of the previous task) will be ignored.

But if you still think it is a "nuclear" option, you can just use `chunks` of size 1 ([docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chunks))

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer still haven't found a good way to solve this, so how chunks solve the issue of not returning the results in the task chain? Also for the immutable signature I dont understand the difference you are trying to explain, if in our current code we modify the signature and then I go and make it immutable I might break something else right? I will stop that data from being passed in. So how is making the signature immutable and simply ignoring the return data the same thing?

Comment: I believe considering the two options as equivalent 1)ignoring the return results and 2)making the task signature immutable, it involves a lot of assumptions. It MIGHT be the case for someone, but it is not generally the same at all. So it shouldnt be proposed without asterisks, cause someone might not understand the difference.

Comment: `chunks` just processes tasks in tasks list in batches, there is no return value handling so if you want to just process your task list one by one you would use chunks of 1. But the point about immutable signature you are missing that it is not for the whole function, but for the funtion call, meaning for exmaple `task(im_sig1)`, `task(sig2)` - here same task called with different arguments which means signatures are different (in terms of celery), but we may say that first is immutable, and second is not. First task when will be executed will ignore result argument, but second is not.